# Private Unit Test Methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

**NOTE:** I am ***NOT*** asking how to unit test private methods.

What I am asking about is the proper way to have private test methods in a Unit Test (or XUnit in this case) class. Let me show you what I mean:

```
public class EndToEndTest
{
    private Foo _foo { get; set;}
    private Bar _bar { get; set;}

    [Fact]
    public async Task EndToEnd()
    {
      await TestFoo();
      await TestBar();
      await TestFooBar();
    }

    [Fact]
    private async Task TestFoo()
    {
      _foo = await FooService();
      Assert.NotNull(_foo);
    }

    [Fact]
    private async Task TestBar()
    {
      _bar = await BarService();
      Assert.NotNull(_bar );
    }

    [Fact]
    private async Task TestFooBar()
    {
      var result = FooBarService(_foo, _bar)
      Assert.NotNull(result);
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the final test is dependent on the first two, and if run alone, it will fail. This works great! But the only exception is that when I look at `FooBarService`, VisualStudio doesn't seem to fully recognize `private async Task TestFooBar()` as a valid test... or somethin' like that.

After running the public test `EndToEnd`, the FooBarService method is showing this:

[image]

This is what I need it to be:

[image]

One of the references is the API and the other is the unit test. So VS is seeing that there is a test method that references the service method, but it doesn't recognize that the method was executed.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve with private tests. You can call your private methods from your public methods without marking them as `[Fact]`.

Comment: The framework requires test methods to be public for it to be recognized.

Comment: @Orifjon - what I'm trying to achieve is not having the private tests executed when you hit the green arrow button to run all tests.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi - I was afraid of that. Is there some way to exclude certain tests (aka: the ones I have markeed as private) from executing when running all the tests?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston if you don't want to run them separately and want to run as part of your public method, just remove `[Fact]` attribute.

Comment: @Orifjon I tried that, but the problem still remains. On the service methods, VS still does not recognize the test method that references it as having been executed. It's only if I move all the code inside '`private TestFoo()` into 'EndToEnd()' that it gets recognized.

Comment: Why do you want them to be recognized? And what do you mean by recognized? Not executed when you run `EndToEnd` test?

Comment: @Orifjon I want it to be recognized so that it doesn't get flagged in Sonarqube as not passing a test. And by 'recognized' I mean I need the method to realize that the test which references it was executed and ran successfully.

Comment: If you remove the [Fact] attribute but make them public, what happens to the statistics?

Answer (score 1):

The framework and VS requires test methods to be public for them to be recognized.

Ideally your `EndToEnd` test should be

```
[Fact]
public async Task EndToEnd() {
    //Arrange
    Foo _foo = await FooService();
    Assert.NotNull(_foo);

     Bar _bar = await BarService();
     Assert.NotNull(_bar );

    //Act
    var result = FooBarService(_foo, _bar)

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: Understood. I was hoping to avoid putting all the code into a single method only because it's going to be a huge method, and when I debug, it becomes harder to skip over some tests and drill into others.